# How good practice and how is Transient Objects in POJO / Models in Hibernate Objects through "Program To Interface"?

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, interface

I am working on basic financial/banking projects. There is "Money" with different contexts, not only currency type texts but also I need other manipulations.

In DB, I persist the amount of money as NUMBER field, and in Hibernate as BigDecimal type object. Let's say `Transfer` is an object mapped to a table which has the information of money transfer between two people;

```
@Entity
class Transfer {
    @Id @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private Person from; //mapped personId

    @Column
    private Person to; //mapped personId

    @Column
    private BigDecimal amount;

    //... setters & getters 
}
```

But actually; almost always I need the amount as Money and with special toString() method: asText() , not only the BigDecimal object and because I need this exactly:

```
Transfer t = dao.getMySpecialTransferObject();
System.out.println(t.money.asText());
```

But I still need the amount directly, because I need to do some calculations on the amount of money. (And I need Money type objects in other Entities as well)

Now I guess I need to create such a class;

```
class Money {
    private BigDecimal amount;
    //... setters & getters

    public String asText(){
        String textToReturn = "The amount of this money is: " + amount.toString;
        // ... and some locale information and manipulation on textToReturn
        return textToReturn;
    }
}
```

As complexicity grows, Design Patterns say "program to interface", then I think I will do this Money as interface and an implementation;

```
interface Money{
    public String asText();
}

class BasicMoney implement Money{
    private BigDecimal amount;
    //... setters & getters

    public String asText(){
        String textToReturn = "The amount of this money is: " + amount.toString();
        // ... and some locale information and manipulation on textToReturn
        return textToReturn;
}
```

So I want to edit my POJO "Transfer" with "Money" type object not as amount.

```
@Entity
class Transfer {
    @Id @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private Person from; //mapped personId

    @Column
    private Person to; //mapped personId

    @Column
    // Not anymore: private BigDecimal amount;
    private Money money;

    //... setters & getters 
}
```

Alright, now here is the question:

My POJO "Transfer" would have same "Money" type object but what about DB relations? Money is not a persistent object in DB, so I might use @Transient annotation but **I still need a coupling/relation between Money and the "amount" column in DB**. How should I keep this relation on POJO?

Note; We are doing this formatting etc. with util classes (without interfaces or transient objects) but I am not sure about this if this is the best practice and I don't want to develop util classes anymore unless there is no better solution.

Comment: The way your amount is displayed should have nothing to do with your persistent model. This logic should be in the presentation layer, not in the model layer. Keep your field as a BigDecimal.

Comment: OK, but then the problem changes to another context. Shall I still have a Util class to format all amounts whenever I need? I feel like it is against to DRY. or maybe I do something very wrong which doesn't point here. I want to go with patterns but I couldn't find a solution/meaning for this -presentation+logic layers vs persistence layer- ++"program to interface"

Comment: Yes, using a MoneyFormatter object to format money amounts is the right way to do. Just like you have a DateFormat to format dates. Or a NumberFormat to format numbers. It seems that you're looking for a problem to solve with patterns, rather than looking for a pattern to solve a problem. This generally leads to bad design.

Comment: Exactly, I am getting a perspective / a way to solution and I see that I am going to the wrong way as you stated. But I can't get the right perspective yet. To make this formatting problem less complex, how should I approach to this design?

Comment: It's not complex. You use BigDecimal in your entity, and you use a formatter class to transform it into the format you want. No need to use dozens of patterns to solve a simple problem. KISS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your field as BigDecimal and just add helper class with static function which formats/displays your amount of money. 
In this case extracting Money interface doesn't make sense, because you have only "toString" method.
Keep in mind the KISS principle.